# Change MySQL query from WHERE to LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, asterisk

I have a query which reports on Asterisk call usage and queue statistics. The query currently uses MySQL WHERE clauses to join the tables and filter the data.

This is how the query looks at present:

```
SELECT 
    c.name as 'Agent',
    e.extended_number AS 'Extension',
    COUNT(ql.`time`) AS 'Total Inbound Calls',
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(1) 
    FROM
        call_history ch,
        ast_queue_mstatus qm
    WHERE
        ch.start >= (DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()),
            INTERVAL 10050 MINUTE))
            AND ch.start <= (DATE(NOW()))
            AND ch.calltype = 'out'
            AND ch.flow = 'out'
            AND ch.extension_number = qm.membername
            AND qm.membername = e.extended_number
    GROUP BY qm.membername) AS 'Total Outbound Calls',
    FORMAT(SUM(CAST(ql.arg2 AS UNSIGNED)) / 60, 2) AS 'Total Inbound Duration',
    FORMAT(AVG(CAST(ql.arg2 AS UNSIGNED)) / 60, 2) AS 'Avg Inbound Duration',
    FORMAT(AVG(CAST(ql.arg1 AS UNSIGNED)) / 60, 2) AS 'Avg Caller Hold Time'
FROM
    ast_queue_log ql,
    ast_queue_mstatus qs,
    client c,
    extension e
WHERE
    ql.queuename = '1234'
    AND ql.`time` >= (DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
    AND ql.`time` <= (DATE(NOW()))
    AND (ql.event = 'COMPLETEAGENT'
    OR ql.event = 'COMPLETECALLER'
    OR ql.event = 'COMPLETETRANSFER')
    AND RIGHT(ql.agent, 8) = qs.membername
    AND qs.membername = e.extended_number
    AND e.client_id = c.id      
GROUP BY ql.agent
ORDER BY c.name;
```

The problem that I have is that I need to return outbound call results for queue members that have not received any inbound calls. At the moment if there are no records in `ast_queue_log` then the `WHERE` clause excludes the records, which means they do not get picked up by the scalar sub query.

How can I change this query so I get all call records from `call_history` where there is a corresponding record in `ast_queue_mstatus`?

Sorry if this is too complex or there is not enough info, I can try to simplify if this makes no sense!

Comment: I gave an answer, but now I see that the core of the answer (move conditions from where to left join) is already in your title. Makes me wonder: if you know this already, why did you ask?

Comment: @GolezTrol thanks for the answer, the reason I asked the question was that I understood that left join was the answer, but could not understand the syntax and what was required. Your answer helped very much and I hope to implement this afternoon :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's time to ditch those old comma separated list of tables and use the join standard that was introduced in 1992 (yes). :-)

Because then you can use a `LEFT JOIN`. With this kind of join, the relationship is optional. That is, all rows in the first table are returned (if they match the conditions in the WHERE clause), but the joined table doesn't have to have records as well.
If it doesn't, a row is still returned, but the fields are filled with `NULL` value.

```
SELECT 
    c.name as 'Agent',
    e.extended_number AS 'Extension',
    COUNT(ql.`time`) AS 'Total Inbound Calls',
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(1) 
    FROM
        call_history ch
        INNER JOIN ast_queue_mstatus qm 
          ON qm.membername = ch.extension_number
    WHERE
        ch.start >= (DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 10050 MINUTE))
        AND ch.start <= (DATE(NOW()))
        AND ch.calltype = 'out'
        AND ch.flow = 'out'
        AND ch.extension_number = e.extended_number
    GROUP BY 
       ch.extension_number) AS 'Total Outbound Calls',
    FORMAT(SUM(CAST(ql.arg2 AS UNSIGNED)) / 60, 2) AS 'Total Inbound Duration',
    FORMAT(AVG(CAST(ql.arg2 AS UNSIGNED)) / 60, 2) AS 'Avg Inbound Duration',
    FORMAT(AVG(CAST(ql.arg1 AS UNSIGNED)) / 60, 2) AS 'Avg Caller Hold Time'
FROM
    client c,
    INNER JOIN extension e 
        ON e.client_id = c.id
    INNER JOIN ast_queue_mstatus qs 
        ON qs.membername = e.extended_number
    LEFT JOIN ast_queue_log ql 
        ON ql.queuename = '1234'
        AND ql.`time` >= (DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
        AND ql.`time` <= (DATE(NOW()))
        AND (
            ql.event = 'COMPLETEAGENT'
            OR ql.event = 'COMPLETECALLER'
            OR ql.event = 'COMPLETETRANSFER')
        AND RIGHT(ql.agent, 8) = qs.membername
GROUP BY ql.agent
ORDER BY c.name;
```

You can use `RIGHT JOIN` as well to join the other way around (first table is optional). But in general this is harder to interpret.